# How to access a file by its path within a shared library plugin with a Unity Android App

Tags: android, opencv, unity-game-engine

I have written a native shared library (.so) in Android Studio which uses OpenCV cascade classifiers. The classifiers have a *load* method that requires the path to a file and this must be called before they can be used.

I can call the *load* method correctly in Android Studio by first placing the required files in the *res/raw* directory of the project. Then I create a *File* resource in the Android App which uses the shared library:

```
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lbpcascade_frontalface);
    File rsrcDir = context.getDir("rsrc", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File rsrc = new File(rsrcDir, "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(rsrc);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    is.close();
    os.close();
    return rsrc;
```

In my shared library (c++) I can then access the file from the following path:

```
/data/data/com.company.product/app_rsrc/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml
```

And this works like a charm.

But now I need to use the shared library from Unity. I've been able to access the contents of the file, which resides in a "StreamingAssets" folder, using the following script:

```
IEnumerator LoadRsrcs()
{
    var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
    if (filePath.Contains("://"))
    {
        var www = new WWW(filePath);
        yield return www;
        result = www.text;
    }
}
```

And then *result* holds the contents of "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml" after the *www* object has extracted the file data from the *apk* file.

But, how do I actually pass the file path to my shared library? I can't just pass the *filepath* variable because its prefixed with *jar:file://*. I.e:

```
"jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/";
```

I guess I would first need to write the contents to a *File* object in the Unity Script somehow and then pass the path to that *File* object as I've done in Android Studio. But without the *context* object which the Android API provides, how would I do that?

Any help/advice much appreciated, or if anyone can suggest a better method of achieving the same result I'm all ears!

Comment: It looks like you merely need to find code to write a file in Unity.  Bear in mind that Android Studio is not a language - it is merely an IDE for working with Android java code.